# Run x86 binary onto Power 9 architecture

Tags: x86, binary, cross-platform

What are the best options in order to try to run a x86 compiled binary onto a IBM "Power 9" processor? Unfortunately I do not have the source code, and the binary was not compiled with debug info, so I can not recompile it.

Comment: an emulator like `qemu` would be the obvious thing.  If it's a Linux binary on Power Linux, you can use `qemu-user` to only emulate system calls for one process, instead of emulating an entire system running a kernel.

Answer (score 6):

As @Peter Cordes mentioned in the comment, The first option is full emulation (emulating x86_64 kernel and apps), the other is QEMU’s user mode translation (emulating only user-mode, translating syscalls to a running ppc64 kernel). Here, we are going to use QEMU user-mode translation.

You should have a working Gentoo ppc64 installation which can achieved using [Catalyst](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Catalyst) on x86, the next step is to get an x86_64 cross-dev environment if you don’t have it already from Catalyst preparation. It will create a directory /usr/x86_64-multilib-linux-gnu/ and it is made by cross-x86_64-multilib-linux-gnu/glibc and similar ebuilds.

Then you need QEMU with proper targets (add this to make.conf and emerge qemu):

```
QEMU_USER_TARGETS="x86_64"
```

To allow running x86_64 apps like any other app, binfmt_misc (CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC) needs to be enabled in the kernel and x86_64 ELF definition loaded. Either look at /etc/init.d/qemu-binfmt (Open-RC) or add this file /etc/binfmt.d/qemu-x86_64.conf and enable systemd-binfmt service (for systemd):

```
:x86_64:M::\x7fELF\x02\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x3e
```

This will allow running x86_64 binaries directly using qemu-x86_64 automatically.

But unless you use chroot, it still won’t work because of a missing ld linker and libraries. Using strace you can see that it tries to load libraries under various paths. It searches for a linker at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 so we have to make a symlink there. For other libraries it tries /lib64/x86_64 and /usr/lib64/x86_64 which are perfect candidates for symlinking. The only remaining path is gcc libs, we can’t add them to /etc/ld.so.conf.d where your ppc64 GCC LDPATH is, so we have to make symlinks for individual files. In other words you want to do something like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/x86_64-multilib-linux-gnu/lib64 /lib64/x86_64
sudo ln -s /usr/x86_64-multilib-linux-gnu/usr/lib64 /usr/lib64/x86_64
sudo ln -s /lib64/x86_64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-multilib-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/x86
```

After that, x86 binaries should auto-magically work just like any other binary, without using an explicit chroot.

You may come across a problem that an executable fails to load libraries despite you see that the x86_64 library is found. All you see is mmap fail with errno EFAULT and errors like “error while loading shared libraries” or “failed to map segment from shared object”. That is because your kernel is not compiled with 4k page size! In kernel menuconfig, it is under “Kernel config” -> “Page size” (CONFIG_PPC_4K_PAGES=y). It has to be 4k, because it is x86_64 standard page size